# Delphi object casting

Tags: delphi, casting

I have a main class and several inherited classes that implement a method with the same name, like this:

```
MainClass = class(TImage)
  //main class methods...
end;

MyClass1 = class(MainClass)
  procedure DoSomething;
end;

MyClass2 = class(MainClass)
  procedure DoSomething;
end;

MyClass3 = class(MainClass)
  procedure DoSomething;
end;
```

I also have a TList containing pointers to object instances (of several classes).
If I want to call the right `DoSomething` procedure for each class, do I use the following?

```
if TList[i] is MyClass1 then
  MyClass1(TList[i]).DoSomething
else if TList[i] is MyClass2 then
  MyClass2(TList[i]).DoSomething
else if TList[i] is MyClass3 then
  MyClass3(TList[i]).DoSomething
```

Is there some casting method that allows me to do this in a few lines of code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, virtual polymorphism :)

```
MainClass = class(TImage)
  procedure DoSomething; virtual;
end;

MyClass1 = class(MainClass)
  procedure DoSomething; override;
end;

MyClass2 = class(MainClass)
  procedure DoSomething; override;
end;

MyClass3 = class(MainClass)
  procedure DoSomething; override;
end;
```

And then just:

```
if TList[i] is MainClass then
  MainClass(TList[i]).DoSomething
```

If you don't want to do an empty `MainClass.DoSomething` procedure, you can also mark it `virtual; abstract;`.

Comment: Polymorphism not inheritance... to be specific

Comment: real polymorphism or virtual? ;)

Answer (score 4):

The virtual inheritance answer is the best for the situation you described where the classes descend from a common base class, but if you have a situation where there is not a common base class between your classes and you need this behavior, you can use interfaces instead to achieve the same result:

```
  IMainInterface = interface
    ['{0E0624C7-85F5-40AF-ADAC-73B7D79C264E}']
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

  MyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMainInterface)
    procedure DoSomething;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  MyClass2 = class(TInterfacedObject, IMainInterface)
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

  MyClass3 = class(TInterfacedObject, IMainInterface)
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;
```

and then using it would look something like this:

```
var
  i: integer;
  list: TInterfaceList;
  main: IMainInterface;
begin
  list := TInterfaceList.Create;

  list.Add(MyClass.create);
  list.Add(MyClass2.Create);
  list.Add(MyClass3.Create);

  for i := 0 to 2 do
    if Supports(list[i], IMainInterface, main) then
      main.DoSomething;

  list.Free;
```

Comment: `Supports()` has overloaded versions that return the interface pointer if found, so you do not have to call the `as` operator, which would redundantly invoke the same interface lookup a second time.

Comment: Thanks, been too long since I messed with interfaces.  I've revised it per your suggestion.

Comment: You can declare list as IInterfaceList, this will add reference counting and save the list.Free (if you leave it as TInterfaceList, do not forget to protect it using try .. finally)